# Angular2 Subscribe Not Working About Service

Tags: angular2-services

Although I have tried many times, but not working EMIT or SUBSCRIBE.

I want to hide app-header, app-sidebar and app-footer in

LoginComponent. Also *ngIf not listening GlobalService variable.

Thanks in advance for your support.

```html
/* App HTML */

<app-header *ngIf="global.showHeader"></app-header>

<app-sidebar *ngIf="global.showSidebar"></app-sidebar>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<app-footer *ngIf="global.showFooter"></app-footer>
```

```js
/* AppComponent */

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  providers: [AppGlobalService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  global = {};

  constructor(private globalService: AppGlobalService) {

    this.globalService.listenUpdated.subscribe(

      data => {

        this.global = data;

      }

    );
  }

  ngOnInit(){
  }
}
```

```js
/* AppGlobalService */

@Injectable()
export class AppGlobalService {

    data={
        showHeader: true,
        showSidebar: true,
        showFooter: true
    };

    listenUpdated = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor(){}

    updateStatus(key: any, value: any) {
        this.data[key] = value;
        console.log('SERVICE ', this.data); // It's working...
    }
}
```

```js
/* LoginComponent */

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login-index',
    templateUrl: './index.component.html',
    providers: [AppGlobalService]
})
export class LoginIndexComponent implements OnInit {

    private data = {};

    constructor(public globalService: AppGlobalService) {
        this.globalService.updateStatus('showHeader', false);
        this.globalService.updateStatus('showSidebar', false);
        this.globalService.updateStatus('showFooter', false);
        this.globalService.listenUpdated.emit(true);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like a better way to do this would be to have a login component, and then lets say a home component. The Login component wouldn't include the html for a sidebar or footer or anything like that at all.

You would use routing to route to the login component when someone is not authenticated. Once they authenticate through the login component you would route to the home component where things like a footer and side bar would be present.

There is a whole [guide to routing](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) that includes login functionality. All of this is viewable in live examples from there as well.